# Open macOS finder to search for file and return selected file as string with C++

Tags: c++, macos

I'm working on a 3d game engine in C++, I use ImGui for the GUI and I want to change my models during run time.  With lots of applications you have a button that opens finder and lets you select the file you want. So how do I open finder with C++ and return the selected file as a string?

Comment: *I'm working on a 3d game engine in C++* – rofl. ymmd.

Comment: Try running `osascript -e 'set theFileListPath to choose file with prompt "Select file: "'` in Terminal, then call that from C++ with `system()` or `popen()` or whatever.